# Randomly generate tiles on a grid without repeats?

Tags: python, pygame

I can't figure out how to make this code not use the the same tile in the grid

```
for i in range(60):
    RandomRow = random.randint(0, MazeSize - 1)
    RandomColumn = random.randint(0, MazeSize - 1)
    TempTile = MapTile('walls', RandomColumn, RandomRow)
    Grid[RandomColumn][RandomRow].append(TempTile)
```

i tried doing this and but the outcome just came out the same

```
for i in range(60):
    RandomRow = random.randint(0, MazeSize - 1)
    RandomColumn = random.randint(0, MazeSize - 1)
    TempTile = MapTile('walls', RandomColumn, RandomRow)
    if TempTile not in Grid: Grid[RandomColumn][RandomRow].append(TempTile)
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wang_tile#Aperiodic_sets_of_tiles

Comment: try to seed your random generator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is nothing that prevents the `random.randint()` function from returning the same selections, so at some point you are likely to get a repeat.

Instead I would create a list of tuples with all the (row, col) pairs in it. This is easily created using two nested for loops appending to a list. Then you can use [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#functions-for-sequences) to select from the list, and then remove the selected entry. This would ensure that you cannot re-select cells.

It would look something like this:

```py
import random

MAX_SELECTIONS = 60
ROWS = 10
COLUMNS = 15

cells = []
for i in range(ROWS):
    for j in range(COLUMNS):
        cells.append((i, j))

random_cells = []
for _ in range(MAX_SELECTIONS):
    selection = random.choice(cells)
    random_cells.append(selection)
    cells.remove(selection)
```

With `random_cells` containing the list of randomized cell selections (`cells` holds the remaining un-selected cells when this finishes).

To more closely match what you have above:

```py
import random

MAX_SELECTIONS = 60
ROWS = MazeSize
COLUMNS = MazeSize

cells = []
for i in range(ROWS):
    for j in range(COLUMNS):
        cells.append((i, j))

for _ in range(MAX_SELECTIONS):
    selection = random.choice(cells)
    cells.remove(selection)

    RandomRow = selection[0]
    RandomColumn = selection[1]
    TempTile = MapTile('walls', RandomColumn, RandomRow)
    Grid[RandomColumn][RandomRow].append(TempTile)
```

EDIT:
I would not do it this way (because it does not stop re-selection but just discards them if they happen). However, I believe that you might fix your current `if` condition like this assuming you only want a tile appended to the `Grid` if that location is empty. :

```py
for i in range(60):
    RandomRow = random.randint(0, MazeSize - 1)
    RandomColumn = random.randint(0, MazeSize - 1)

    if not Grid[RandomColumn][RandomRow]:
        TempTile = MapTile('walls', RandomColumn, RandomRow)
        Grid[RandomColumn][RandomRow].append(TempTile)
```

Comment: thanks for the help, i had to move some other line of code around but it works perfectly now :)